# How to add web service (ASMX) refernece dynamically in C# (not to do "Add web Refernece" )

Tags: c#, web-services, reference, webclient

How to add webservice reference dynamically ?

I have created a class library project and i need to post data into a web service.

I don't want to consume web service as "Add Web reference" as i dont' want to use APP.CONFIG file and need to load this web service dynamically.

Please suggest me how dynamically i could load this web service inside this class library project ?

pLEASE share some code if possible.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically support different types of web services, they'll have to use an consistent interface so that a single set of classes can use the web services. Which will result in building a separate library.

[Adding a Web reference dynamically at Runtime](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54/adding-a-web-reference-dynamically-at-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral)